# How to organise C# source files in subfolders?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, projects-and-solutions

**BACKGROUND** 
I'm mostly programming in embedded C/C++ but sometimes I have to do some C# programming for our API. For this I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to create an API DLL  for our customers.

The C# API and our C/C++ firmware are using a common set of status codes. I have a Lua script that generates these codes to a .h (for C/C++) and a .cs (for C#) file so they always are in sync.

All source files that are shared across products and platforms are in a special project called "Common" (checked-in to Subversion).

When we create new projects and use any "common" file, we put them in a sub folder called "Common\" so we know that there is no point in messing with them. Subversion will check out these "Common" files as externals of a specific revision used by each project.

In C/C++ it's no problem at all to have source code organized in several levels of folders, all source files have a relative path to the root project folder.

**THE PROBLEM** 
So in this C# project I organize the source code as usual:

```
ProjectRoot\source.cs
ProjectRoot\Common\EStatusCodes.cs
```

In the `ProjectRoot\` we have all .cs files for this C# project, and in `ProjectRoot\Common\` are the external files from subversion's "Common" project.

So after the checkout of the external EStatusCodes.cs into the `ProjectRoot\Common\` folder I add it to the C# project by "Add->Add Existing..." and then I point out the `ProjectRoot\Common\EStatusCodes.cs` file.

The file shows up in the Project but for some reason Visual Studio has COPIED the file form the `ProjectRoot\Common` folder to the `ProjectRoot\` folder and is then using the copy! (The file's path in properties is set to the `ProjectRoot\` folder.

So If we add more status codes to the "Common" project, this C# project don't get the update because Visual Studio now always use the copied version of the file from `ProjectRoot\` and don't care if `ProjectRoot\Common\EStatusCodes.cs` has been updated.

I tried to add the Common folder to "Properties->Reference Path", but it still copies the file every time I add it to the project.

Is it possible at all to have source files somewhere else than in the C# project's root folder?

Comment: I always add files using **Solution Explorer** window. There is a button called **Show All Files**, then I right-click on a needed folder and select **Include In Project** from menu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Add Existing dialog, there should be a small down arrow next to the Add button. If you click this, you'll see an option to "Add As Link". This will add the file as a reference link to the original file and any changes to the original will reflect in your project.

[image]

Comment: Thank you!!! This started to drive me nuts :) I'm not usually working in Visual Studio...

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar way in C# project: **add existing file** to project as **"Add as link"**.

Please refer this link for more details:
https://grantwinney.com/visual-studio-add-file-as-link/